# How to transform ES6 AST into ES5 AST directly?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I learnt that packages like Babel can do the job converting ES6 code to JavaScript in ES5, but can I just start from the ES6 AST I got somewhere?

Comment: So, you have an ES6 AST and you want to create an ES5 AST from it?

Comment: @bali182 Yes. That ES6 AST is generated from other tools. It's also fine if it  outputs JavaScript directly.

Comment: But why don't you just don't parse the ES6 code at all, and let for example Babel do the converting it right into ES5 code? Also, If you would find a tool that converts an AST to something else, it would require the AST to be in a specific format, and you would have to do some nasty transforming (most likely)

Comment: @bali182 Yes. It was actually an AltJS language, I suppose it might interesting if I generates ES6 AST and let babel or whatever that transforms AST into ES5 JavaScript .

Answer (score 2):

I posted a similar question in babel's Issues and got an anwser from the maintainer:

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1122

```
require("babel").transform.fromAST(ast, originalCode, options);
```

variable `originalCode` could be `null` and that will finish this task.

Comment: Some poking around the source code revealed the same thing: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/src/babel/transformation/index.js#L12-L19